# Laravel not finding the controller located in other folder

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

I'm trying to implement a clean architecture in laravel, thus I'm moving my own code to a `src` folder.

My controller is located in `src\notebook\infrastructure` but when i call it from `routes\web.php` this way:

```
Route::get('/notebook', 'src\notebook\infrastructure\NotebooksController@show');
```

i got this error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [src\notebook\infrastructure\NotebooksController] does not exist.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/notebook
```

i also changed the namespace value in the class `RouteServiceProvider` from:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

to

```
protected $namespace = '';
```

This is my notebook controller class:

```
namespace src\notebook\infrastructure;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NotebooksController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        echo 'controller from infrastructure folder';
    }
}
```

My laravel and php version in `composer.json` are:

```
"php": "^7.2.5",
"laravel/framework": "^7.24",
```

I feel like i'm missing something stupid but can't figure it out what.

Comment: did you tell composer about this `src` directory that it will now have to autoload the `src` namespace for?

Comment: No, how can i do that?

Comment: look at the `psr-4` section in the`autoload` section of the `composer.json` and see how Laravel sets it up for the `App` namespace and add an entry for your `src` in a similar way

Comment: OMG you're a god!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add src folder into the autoload?
In composer.json file, you must have something like this:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Src\\": "src/" // add this
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
```

After changing it run `composer dump-autoload`.
And also don't forget to follow psr-4 rules and use Studly case namespace and class names.

```
namespace Src\Notebook\Infrastructure;
```